# Mysterious error by parsing French dates on OSX

Tags: r, date

I've a character vector with dates in French. I would like to convert them to a date format in R. It seems to work but there are some mysterious errors. For instance, R recognize "30 juin 2012" but not "30 juillet 2012" :

```
> as.Date("30 juin 2012", format = "%d %B %Y")
[1] "2012-06-30"
> as.Date("28 février 2012", format = "%d %B %Y")
[1] "2012-02-28"
> as.Date("30 juillet 2012", format = "%d %B %Y")
[1] NA
```

Do you have any explanation ?

PS : my local setting is French UTF8

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/C/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8"
```

Comment: hmmm.  When I do `Sys.setlocale(locale="fr_FR.UTF-8")`, all your code works for me.  (I didn't have a French language pack, and I'm on Linux, so I ran `sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8` followed by `sudo dpg-reconfigure locales` first).  Maybe try with a lowercase `%b` instead of `%B`?  What is your OS?

Comment: All your code works for me too by setting my locale to french. What is the output of `format(as.Date(c("2000-06-01", "2000-07-01")), "%B")` ?

Comment: @GSee : I'm on Mac OS 10.8 and I've got the same results with %b instead of %B

Comment: @dickoa : Good idea but I still don't see the problem : `> format(as.Date(c("2000-06-01", "2000-07-01")), "%B")
[1] "juin"    "juillet"`

Comment: @PAC I can replicate the problem on OS X. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: Related lubridate bug: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/194

Comment: I can appreciate wanting an answer, but my guess is that this is some sort of really subtle problem with the implementation of the locales on your system: R relies on the OS implementation for most of this sort of date-parsing thing, which is why this and the related `lubridate` bug only happen on some platforms. I can replicate on OS X; I'm currently trying to write a little C program that just uses the `strptime` system call ...

Comment: related (googling "strptime juillet OSX"): http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2009-December/037796.html https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2012-June/009297.html

Answer (score 7):

I don't really have an explanation, but I do have a solution. Having had similar problems with German numbers using "," instead of "." for decimals and some different ways of writing dates too. Here's what I usually do to my data that is not in the correct format:

```
a<-"30 juillet 2012"

b<-gsub(pattern="juillet", a, replacement="july")

as.Date(b, format="%d %B %Y")
[1] "2012-07-30"
```

Hope this helps you out. If "july" doesn't work on your system, you could always replace it with a 7. Like so

```
a<-"30 juillet 2012"
b<-gsub(pattern="juillet", a, replacement="/ 7 /")
b<-gsub(pattern="|| ", b, replacement="")
as.Date(b, format= "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Greetings, Ben

Comment: @Ben_K Thank you for your solution. I can do it this way but I would like to understand why the standard solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

As GSee said, it's a locale issue.  Set your locale to French using `Sys.setlocale` and your code example runs OK.

Under Linux (I think OS X too, but not tested):

```
Sys.setlocale(locale="fr_FR")
```

Under Windows:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale="French_France")
```

The `UTF-8`in GSee's comment is the character encoding, and is optional.  See `?iconvlist` for more info.

Comment: It still doesn't work : `> Sys.setlocale(locale="fr_FR")
[1] "fr_FR/fr_FR/fr_FR/C/fr_FR/fr_FR.UTF-8"
> as.Date("5 juillet 2011", format = "%d %B %Y")
[1] NA`

Comment: And juillet (July) seems to be the only month which is not recognized by `as.Date()`

Comment: +1 I can also return the dates (including juillet) just fine by switching locales

Comment: @SimonO101 you're not on OS X are you?

Comment: @GSee no I'm at work and on Windows x64. I have a Mac at home which I can test on

Comment: might want to delete this since in fact the solution *doesn't* work on OS (as explained in other answers), so this feels like it just adds noise ...

Comment: For this to work install the locale if its not already  installed.  From the shell:  `sudo locale-gen fr_FR`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck , the OP's problem is **not** that the locale (`fr_FR`) isn't installed.  The problem is that there's an OSX bug in the implementation of the locale.

Comment: @RichieCotton Here no need to change all the local , just `LC_TIME `option. Generally , this what I do : `locT <- Sys.getlocale('LC_TIME');Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME','French_France'); Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME',locT)`

Answer (score 4):

(An answer to "why?" and the "how answer" was already posted. So will leave this as what seems to be the "deep" explanation, even if it isn't a patch on OSX.  And it's a bug in OSX, not R.)

Despite setting my locale (also on a Mac) to "fr_FR", the LC_TIME setting remains 'en_US'

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
> Sys.setlocale(locale="fr_FR") # Should have category="LC_ALL"
[1] "fr_FR/fr_FR/fr_FR/C/fr_FR/en_US.UTF-8"
> month.abb
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
> month.name
 [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"     
 [8] "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"
```

After reading the Github bug for lubridate, it appears I'm not reporting anything new. Macs have this bug I guess. The help pages say the 'month.abb' and 'month.name' values should be used as references, but changing them is also ineffective. (Perhaps they are read at Startup?) It has been reported on SIG-R-Mac: http://markmail.org/search/?q=+list%3Aorg.r-project.r-sig-mac+french+locale#query:%20list%3Aorg.r-project.r-sig-mac%20french%20locale+page:1+mid:oie7r5qksadmzjia+state:results

And then reading further along we see that the bug is in OSX and has been there for some time:
http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2009-December/037796.html

I'm only on Lion, but will be updating to Mavericks "real soon now."

Comment: I think this *is* an answer, since the question was "Do you have any explanation ?"  (bonus points for a workaround).  (This is essentially the same as my answer).

Comment: Yeah, the same. You used Google. I used Markmail. And he has been given a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Some googling on "OSX strptime juillet" produces this comment from Peter Dalgaard http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-sig-mac/12696r26eh/as-date-does-not-work-with-format-b :

> Looks like this is
>
> http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2009-December/037796.html
>
> which was fixed in May 2010, but apparently hasn't percolated down to
>   the OSX updates yet. (Still there in local build on Lion, so not just
>   CRAN binaries. Insert appropriate rant about Open Source and
>   commercial vendors here...)
>
> Summary of bug: strptime with %B goes through the months and checks
>   for full name, then abbreviation. Problem is that "jui" of "juillet"
>   matches abbr. for "juin"! but "llet" mismatches %Y and we get the NA.

So it's a BSD bug that persists in OSX.

Looks like you're going to have to use something like @Ben K's solution to work around this.  (Sorry.)