# R Convert concatenated date in chr format to dd-mm-yyyy date format

Tags: r

I've got a date in character format (month in French) that looks like this -

```
date = "30juillet2021"
```

I'd like to convert it to dd-mm-yyyy date format

Desired output

```
30/07/2021
```

I've tried a number of solutions on stackoverflow, but none seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: seems this problem has been tackled somewhere else https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856415/mysterious-error-by-parsing-french-dates-on-osx

Answer (score 0):

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME', "French_France")
[1] "French_France.1252"

as.Date(date, "%d%B%Y")
[1] "2021-07-30"

format(as.Date(date, "%d%B%Y"), "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "30/07/2021"
```

Comment: I get '[1] NA' as output

Comment: @Varun did you run the first line?

Comment: Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "French_France") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "French_France" cannot be honored

Comment: @Varun seems you are on mac/linux. Try `lubridate::dmy(date, locale = "fr_FR.utf8")`